# Coldfusion - Get Variable from another page using Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, variables, coldfusion

I am facing problem on getting variable from another ColdFusion  page via Ajax. I have 2 files which are uploadForm.cfm and act_ajaxAddEditFile.cfm

In uploadForm.cfm file have Ajax code. This Ajax will do submit form. This ajax also will open file act_ajaxAddEditFile.cfm file for validation. After validation done, I want variable #resultError# from act_ajaxAddEditFile.cfm pass to Ajax.

uploadForm.cfm (Ajax):

```
$jq('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var type = $jq('#type').val();
  var form = document.getElementById('fileForm');
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'pages/subactions/act_ajaxAddEditFile.cfm', true);
  xhr.send(formData);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      //I want to put variable #resultError# from act_ajaxAddEditFile.cfm here to do IF Statment.       
      var type = $jq('#type').val();
      $jq("#list" + type).load("pages/includes/inc_listFileResult.cfm", {
        type: type,
        qst_id: <cfoutput>#form.qst_id#</cfoutput> 
      }, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
          var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
          $jq("#list" + type).html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
      });
      $jq("#" + type).empty();
      $jq("." + type).removeClass('hide');
    }
  }
});
```

ajaxAddEdit.cfm (variable):

```
<cfif result.status EQ 'OK'>
  <cfoutput>upload FILE</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
  <cfoutput>Fail upload FILE</cfoutput>
  <cfset resultError = #result.error#>
</cfif>
```

Comment: For that you need to output the variable in your cfm page instead of `<cfoutput>Fail upload FILE</cfoutput>`. `<cfset resultError = #result.error#><cfoutput>#resultError#</cfoutput>`. Which datatype is `resultError`? You can do what I mentioned if it is a string or you can use some encoding to display it.

Comment: But sir, I want this variable #resultError# go to inside Ajax code which is in uploadForm.cfm file. Now this variable #resultError# in inc_listFileResult.cfm file. I want to know how to pass this variable #resultError# from inc_listFileResult.cfm to uploadForm.cfm file.

thank you,

Comment: You can print the variable in the ajaxAddEdit.cfm and get it in the upload.cfm in `xhr.responseText` variable.

Comment: Yes Sir! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just output the `result.error` if it is a string or else you can use some encoding to display it. The text will be received by the ajax call. Then you can use it as per your need.

```
<cfif result.status EQ 'OK'>
  <cfoutput>upload FILE</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
  <cfoutput>#result.error#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

That being said, there are some changes you can make to your code. Since you are using jQuery, you can change the basic JavaScript ajax call with jQuery `ajax` or `post`. So that the code looks more simple like this below.

```js
$jq('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var type = $jq('#type').val();
  $jq.post('pages/subactions/act_ajaxAddEditFile.cfm', $('#fileForm').serialize(), function(resp, status, jqxhr) {
    if (jqxhr.readyState == 4 && jqxhr.status == 200) {
      alert(resp);
      var type = $jq('#type').val();
      $jq("#list" + type).load("pages/includes/inc_listFileResult.cfm", {
        type: type,
        qst_id: '<cfoutput>#form.qst_id#</cfoutput>'
      }, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
          var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
          $jq("#list" + type).html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
      });
      $jq("#" + type).empty();
      $jq("." + type).removeClass('hide');
    }
  });
});
```